# Feeding vectorized data to keras

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, keras

I am working on using some `name:gender` data to build and train a model that could predict the gender. I am trying the basics as I read about ML and probably got many things wrong. I haven't yet learnt how to generate and feed all the features that I want the network to use in its training. At this point, I am trying to prepare my data and have keras accept it for training.

I am trying to build a dictionary or chars in the names and feed each vectorized name into the model:

```py
names_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(cm.Name.objects.all().values())).drop('id', axis=1)
names_frame['name'] = names_frame['name'].str.lower()
names_frame['gender'] = names_frame['gender'].replace('Male',0).replace('Female', 1)
names_list = names_frame['name'].values
names_dict = list(enumerate(set(list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, names_list)))))
names_frame['vectorized'] = names_frame['name'].apply(vectorize, args=(names_dict,))
names_frame.sample()
```

I end up with this:

```
       gender   gender_count  name   vectorized
20129  1        276           meena  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, ...
```

Then I build the model and try to train it:

```py
X = names_frame['vectorized']
Y = names_frame['gender']
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

And get the following exception:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Both `names_frame['gender'].shape` and `names_frame['vectorized'].shape` are `(34325,)`

Basically, I am trying to feed it the vector and the gender classifier, but looks like something is not right with the input format? `X` is `pandas.Series` - I tried converting it to `np.array` but this didn't help.

The `input_dim` parameter denotes the number of input elements I am giving the network to deal with. I have `1` since I am trying to give it an array of values. Should I be giving it `26`? But when I change it to `26`, it's giving me a different exception:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_46_input to have shape (26,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

This is probably because I am not giving it 26 individual pandas columns I assume - do I need to convert my array to columns or unpack the array somehow?

Comment: Can you print names_frame['vectorized'].shape

Comment: Both `names_frame['gender'].shape` and `names_frame['vectorized'].shape` are (34325,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"vectorized": [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],
                   "gender": [1,0,1]})

# convert the inner list to numpy array
# X = np.array([np.array(l) for l in df["vectorized"]])
# or use a simpler way:
X = np.vstack(df["vectorized"])
Y = df["gender"].values

model = Sequential()
# input_dim should be X.shape[1]
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: You can use \np.vstack(df['vectorized']) , in converting to array :)

Comment: @NagaKiran Thanks! I tried to find a function doing the same thing but fails.